# Почему при открытии попапа "оставить отзыв" страница перематыватся наверх?

Tags: html, css, jquery

[ссылка на страницу](http://partnernkt.ru/kristal/index.html)

никак не пойму в чем дело(

Comment: с любой верстей Jquery

Comment: плагин используете какой-нибудь? команды, по типу `window.scrollTo(0, 0);`?

Comment: Нет, используются ссылки с href, сожержащим "#". <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('call').style.display='block';">заказать звонок</a>

Comment: вместо `href="#"` напишите: `href="javascript:void(0);"`

Comment: УРА! вы мой спаситель

Comment: желаю успехов и не болеть :)

Comment: @meine: В ответ оформите.

Comment: @UModeL, да лень что-то, если хотите - оформите, я за баллами не гонюсь)

Comment: Всем огромное спасибо! Успехов и здоровья!